# Setting gauge limits in highcharts using variable

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a simple gauge chart, but I wish to alter it dynamically, for instance, I would like to have the scale limits set based on data extracted from a database. how would I achieve this?

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="chart-A" class="chart"></div>
```

```
var axismin = 10;

$(function(axismin,axismax) {


  $('#chart-A').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Gauge'
      },
      pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
      },
      // the value axis
      yAxis: {
        min: axismin,
        max: 100,
      },
      series: [{
        data: [1]
      }]
    },
    // Add some life
    function(chart) {
      if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function() {
          var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
            newVal,
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

          newVal = point.y + inc;
          if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 100) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
          }

          point.update(newVal);

        }, 500);
      }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samarkh/3d1r5L1q/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose from database you call min and max values.

```
$(function() {

 //suppose using php
  var axismin = <?php echo  $axismin ?>;
  var axismax = <?php echo  $axismax ?>;

  function init(axismin, axismax) {
    ......
  }
  init(axismin, axismax); //call chart function with arguments
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha9s1uqk/) demo

Comment: I like this as it also shows a way to get the data from the MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts provide some functions for altering already rendered chart. For updating `yAxis.min` and `yAxis.max` values you can use `setExtremes` or `update`.

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update